# Не работает if условие на false

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Хочу узнать, как можно удалить все false элементы из массива в js, проблема в том, что на элементе false что-то идёт не так. Совсем уже запутался. ( Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!(arr[i])) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(bouncer([7, 'ate', '', false, 9]));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удаляйте в противоположном направлении. И все будет работать. Где-то так:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  for(var i = arr.length-1; i>= 0; i--) {
    if (!(arr[i])) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(bouncer([7, 'ate', '', false, 9]));
```

Либо используйте функцию [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: Спасибо работает, а не подскажите, почему так? Про filter не знал, удобно.

Comment: Дошло, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

`!(arr[i])` должен, по идее, одинаково отдавать true в случае, если там '',0,false,undefined и т.д.

Используйте `!(arr[i]===false)`

up:
И еще если элемент удаляете, надо `i--`, иначе следующий элемент будет пропущен.

Comment: Не будет срабатывать, я так пробовал уже(

Comment: А вот и объяснение) Спасибо большое дошло)

Answer (score 0):

А можно ведь сделать всё намного проще :) это же учебное задание и стандартная функция `typeof` легко находит все false:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof(arr[i]) == "boolean") {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(bouncer([7, 'ate', '', false, true, 9]));
```

Добавил в [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/c6gvgrm0/) true, чтобы никто не усомнился, что находятся только false